# VBA : Detect a change of Activeworkbook

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a `XLA AddIn` macro with a main menu `Userform`. I need to enable/disable boutons on this menu userform according to the `Activeworkbook`.

My problem is that I don't know how to update the `Userform` when the user change or close the `Activeworkbook`.

I do have a `UserForm_Activate`, which update the `Userform`. But that event is not triggered when the user close the `Activeworkbook` then click on the `Userform`.

I would need to update the `Userform` either :

- as soon as the `Activeworkbook` is changed or closed
- or as soon as the user reach the `Userform` (ie. before he can click on any control).

How would you proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

In the ThisWorkbook module of your xla:

```
Private WithEvents xlApp as Excel.Application
```

You will then see that xlApp has events such as WorkbookActivate and WorkbookDeactivate etc.

Comment: If so, wouldn't the code launch each and every time the user change workbook, whether the user is using the macro (some forms are opened...) or not ? I wouldn't want the macro running continuously when the user is just using Excel.

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted? There is also a WorkbookBeforeClose event.

Comment: The macro, being an `XLA AddIn`, is installed on the PC. But it's launched only when the user need it (from a ribbon menu), since it can use a lot of memory... Thus, I'd rather not have pieces of the macro running continuously in Excel (all the more each and every time change workbook) when the user is not using the macro, but just using Excel. I'd like to find a way to update the `Userform`, **when this userform is open**.

Comment: Need more details please. How would you then use this xlApp to invoke a sub on WorkbookActivate?

Comment: In the Object bar (the dropdown immediately above the code window) select xlApp. Then in the Procedure bar to the right of it you will see many events, one of them being WorkbookActivate. Click it and you will see a procedure stub is created which receives a Workbook object as a parameter - it is the workbook being activated.

Comment: Private WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "Workbook change detected"
End Sub.   Didn't work for me in ThisWorkbook of xlam add-in